# No unity after login to main user account

Tags: unity, compiz, login, lightdm

Yesterday my computer stayed open all night and then when battery was empty it turned off. Its normal for my computer. But when at morning I turned it on, there wasn't login screen. It crashed everytime.
After reinstalling Xorg, lightdm, ubuntu-desktop and doing some other things login screen appeared. But after login I can see only my desktop and System crashed warnings that appears in ubuntu from times when unity came.
In guest mode everything works well. I created new user and assigned him as admin (All privilages) and logged in to his account. Now I'm writing from that user account and everything works very well. So, How I can restore my main account?

Selecting Unity Plugin from ccsm not worked (login to user account, go to tty1 and entering export DISPLAY=:0 and then ccsm + switching to F7). + reinstalled ccsm
Half of space in SSD is empty, so its not memory problem.
Wallpaper in its place :D

Comment: See here: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381) You may try some of the other answers in that question.

Answer (score 0):

install `unity-tweak-tool` 
terminal : `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

reset unity by running this command :     `unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity`

Answer (score 0):

First of all needed to install graphic card driver for intel hd 4000 from different source:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then opening `ccsm` again and select unity plugin. Accepting and enabling all warnigns, there will be a lot than usual.
After that unity menu will be shown. After reboot everything will work as before but there will be a lot warning messages. Another problem is to solve that errors.

I have no idea how after reboot unity can crash in such way.